# Doesn't Enter my constructor

Tags: objective-c, ios

Im using the tabbed view application in xcode 4.3.

Im am simply trying to initislise some variables i have declared in my .h file of my FirstViewController. Im attempting this by creating a constructor in my .m file like so.

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextField *currentGuess;
    IBOutlet UILabel *attemptsMade;
    IBOutlet UILabel *attemptsLeft;
    IBOutlet UITextView *hints;
    int numberToGuess;
    int numberOfGuessesMade;
    int maxGuesses;
    int maxGenNumber;

    NSMutableArray *allGuesses;


}

- (id) init;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

    - (id) init {
        NSLog(@"entered constructor!");

        if(self = [super init]) 
        {
            numberToGuess = 0;
            numberOfGuessesMade = 0;
            maxGuesses = 3;
            maxGenNumber = 10;
        }

        return self;
    }
```

Comment: Tried answers below, ended up using viewDidLoad instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UIViewController doesn't make sense to initialize with the init method.
Normaly you need `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle`

If you building it from a XIB file, than do it like this

You need to place your initialization code in - `(void)awakeFromNib` or `-(void)viewDidLoad`.

Something like this for your case

@implementation FirstViewController

```
- (id) awakeFromNib {
    NSLog(@"entered XIB constructor!");

    numberToGuess = 0;
    numberOfGuessesMade = 0;
    maxGuesses = 3;
    maxGenNumber = 10;

}
```

if non xib then:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle {
    NSLog(@"entered constructor!");

    if(self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle]) 
    {
        numberToGuess = 0;
        numberOfGuessesMade = 0;
        maxGuesses = 3;
        maxGenNumber = 10;
    }

    return self;
}
```

And remember. init is not a "real" constructor as you would learn in OO class.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [UIViewController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), the designated initializer for UIViewController is `initWithNibName:bundle:`. But depending on how your view controller is created (e.g. in code or as part of a storyboard), this might not even be called, and it might be `initWithCoder:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nib. `awakeFromNib` method will be called. Also check whether use variants of init method like , `initWithNibName`, `initWithframe` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code where you create the VC? If you do it from an XIB init will not be called, instead of that you should re-write:

```
initWithNibName
```